# What is pytest result mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-cov

I'm learning about testing in **Python**, and now I'm using **pytest-cov**.

I try to run this command:

```
pytest --cov=myProj tests/ --cov-report term-missing
```

after the testing done I got the report like this:

```
       ----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.6.7-final-0 -----------
Name                                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myProject/__init__.py                                                0       0    100%
myProject/alert.py                                                  14      14      0%   1-21
myProject/api/__init__.py                                            1       0    100%
myProject/api/spaces/__init__.py                                     0       0    100%
myProject/api/spaces/admin.py                                      279     179     36%   154-223, 312-335, 351-398, 422-432, 505-515, 534-565, 591-697
myProject/api/spaces/global.py                                      89      66     26%   35-43, 47-69, 72-92, 96-124
myProject/api/spaces/inventory.py                                   79      79      0%   1-119
myProject/api/spaces/keyword.py                                    134     110     18%   33-42, 46-68, 72-93, 101-112, 116-134, 138-165, 168-190
```

A few things that make me still confuse about the report that I still didn't find it in the [documentation](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) are about:
what is 
**Stmts**, **Miss**, **Cover**, and **Missing**, is that if the result on **Cover** doesn't 100% it means my code still bad or what..?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Stmts` refers to the number of *statements* in your code.

`Miss` refers to the number of statements that have not been run.

`Cover` is test coverage, or `(Stmts - Miss) / (Stmts) * 100`.

`Missing` contains the line numbers of the `Miss` statements.

If coverage is not 100%, that means that there are parts of your code that your tests do not cover, for example:

```
def f(a, b):
    if a > 0:
        return a

    elif a == 0:
        return 0

    else:
        return b

def test_f():
    assert f(10, 10)
```

The above test will only ever enter the `a > 0` branch and will therefore have a test coverage of 33%.

High coverage is not always good (because just covering code doesn't mean that all cases are tested adequately), but low coverage is often bad (because that means your tests are not even touching parts of your code).

Answer (score 2):

- **Stmts** - means the total lines of code you have in a specific file.
- **Miss** - total number of lines that are not covered by unittest.
- **Cover** - percentage of all line of code that are covered by unittest.
- **Missing** - lines of codes that are not covered.

Comment: I'm still don't got it about **Stmts**, because at my report that in my real project, I have 54 lines (whitout  lines break) in my file and 26 lines in my test file (also without line break), but in my report the **Stmts** it showing 28.